# Calling a function as soon as an element is encountered

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have an element on my page with id "some_id". I want to call a function as soon as I encounter this element. Something like following.

```
$("#some_id").call_a_function(function () {
  // do stuff
});
```

Comment: "encounter this element" .. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "encounter this element".  If you mean as soon as the element is parsed, you could always inline some script right after it:

```
<div id="some_id">Hello</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#some_id").call_a_function(function () {  
  // do stuff  
});  
</script>
```

The javascript code will be parsed right after the div.  Of course, this wouldn't be much quicker than using `$(document).ready()` on small pages.

Comment: "encounter this element" means as soon as it is available on the page.

When we write "$("#some_id").click(function () {});", the anonymous 'function' would be called when that element is clicked. However what I want is to call that function as soon as it is available for manipulation.

Comment: @Waseem: a script tag right after the element in the document will execute immediately after the element has been parsed (ie, as soon as it is available).

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this jquery plugin as an alternative to `$(document).ready()`

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/available

Allows you to specify a handler to a DOM element as soon as it becomes available.

Comment: +1 - It's extremely annoying to get a downvote with no explanation, especially when you have seemingly answered the question.  @Downvoter - We're all here to learn, enlighten us on why this answer deserved a downvote so we might further our knowledge.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't agree more. I guess people fear retaliation votes (i've had that happen to me too) too much.